# Please explain Objective-C instance definitions

Tags: objective-c

`NSString * aString;`

What I don't understand is the *, what exactly does that operator do and what else can go there if anything?

Sorry I know this is a rather novice question but I am self taught; whenever I see "*" I think wildcard and I don't see why you would cast an object NSString  ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that aString points to where the NSString object is in memory. You might want to check out [Binky Pointer Fun](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/) ( [youtube version](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6pmWojisM_E) ) to get a hang of what Pointers are!

You can also read a bit more about pointers ( and even Double pointers! ) [here](http://blog.filipekberg.se/2008/11/11/pointers-double-pointers/).

A pointer is exactly what it sounds like, it's something that Points out where to go. Your memory is divided into "boxes" and each box is labeld with what we call a Memory Address. You you write:

`NSString myString;`

it means that you allocate an `NSString` object in memory. But when you decide to write:

`NSString *myString;`

it means that you create a Pointer to an `NSString` somewhere in your memory. In short it means that `myString` in the latter example will contain the Memory Address to the "*real*" 
`NSString` object.

Answer (score 0):

The * means that you are creating a pointer to an object. Note that this is part of the C language, not Objective-C (Objective-C is a strict superset of C).

http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/